# 404 error handling with mako template

Tags: python, cherrypy, mako

Trying to display template rendered by mako on 404 errors, but it still displays standart error page with cherrypy footer and additional message: |In addition, the custom error page failed: TypeError: render_body() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)"
The code:

```
def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
    tmpl = tpl.get_template("404.mako")
    return tmpl.render(status, message)
cherrypy.config.update({'error_page.404': error_page_404})
```

Need help! How to display completely custom error pages with my layout(mako template)?

Full code:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
import os, atexit
import threading
import cherrypy
from mako.template import Template
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup

cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'embedded'})
if cherrypy.engine.state == 0:
    cherrypy.engine.start(blocking=False)
    atexit.register(cherrypy.engine.stop)

localDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
absDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), localDir)
path = os.path.join(absDir,'files')
templ_path = os.path.join(absDir,'html')

tpl = TemplateLookup(directories=[templ_path], input_encoding='utf-8', output_encoding='utf-8',encoding_errors='replace')

def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
    tmpl = tpl.get_template("404.mako")
    return tmpl.render(status, message)
cherrypy.config.update({'error_page.404': error_page_404})

class Root:
    def index(self):
    tmpl = tpl.get_template("index.mako")       
    return tmpl.render(text = 'Some text',url = cherrypy.url())
index.exposed = True    

_application = cherrypy.Application(Root(), None)

import posixpath

def application(environ, start_response):
    environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = posixpath.dirname(environ['SCRIPT_NAME'])
    if environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/':
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''
        return _application(environ, start_response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely raising an error with in your 404 handler and I guess you not setting the `request.error_response` of the cherrypy config like [this](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cperror.html#unanticipated-errors), and about the error of `response_body` check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/mako-discuss/tree/browse_frm/month/2011-02?_done=/group/mako-discuss/browse_frm/month/2011-02?&), you are probably using wrong the [body](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/namespaces.html#the-body-method) of the template.

Edit from the comments:

```
def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
    tmpl = tpl.get_template("404.mako")
    return tmpl.render(stat=status, msg=message)

cherrypy.config.update({'error_page.404': error_page_404})
```

The `render` method, only specify the function behavior with the keyword arguments, you could also be a little more flexible and specify the same function like this:

```
def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
    tmpl = tpl.get_template("404.mako")
    args = {'stat': status,
            'msg': message}
    return tmpl.render(**args)
```

It will make it easier to expand your arguments for the template, I usually use `**args`
for my `render` calls.

But the basically the problem was (as you pointed out), that you where calling render with  non-keyword arguments, and the expected input is just keyword arguments, for the template.

Comment: My 404.mako is just a plain html, no any includes. request.error_response? I don't get it - how to set it up in my case?

Comment: I figured it out! So after `class Root` add

    _cp_config = {'error_page.404': error_page_404}
Then modify `error_page_404` function to this:

    def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
     tmpl = tpl.get_template("404.mako")
     return tmpl.render(stat = status, msg = message)
    cherrypy.config.update({'error_page.404': error_page_404})
And now it works!

Comment: @Zhlobopotam could you make that into an answer with nicely formatted code?

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out :) Thanks to cyraxjoe! Here is the code:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
import os, atexit
import threading
import cherrypy
from mako.template import Template
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup

cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'embedded'})
if cherrypy.engine.state == 0:
    cherrypy.engine.start(blocking=False)
    atexit.register(cherrypy.engine.stop)

localDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
absDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), localDir)
path = os.path.join(absDir,'files')
templ_path = os.path.join(absDir,'html')

tpl = TemplateLookup(directories=[templ_path], input_encoding='utf-8', output_encoding='utf-8',encoding_errors='replace')

def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
    tmpl = tpl.get_template("404.mako")
    return tmpl.render(status, message)
cherrypy.config.update({'error_page.404': error_page_404})

class Root:
    _cp_config = {'error_page.404': error_page_404}
    def index(self):
    tmpl = tpl.get_template("index.mako")       
    return tmpl.render(text = 'Some text',url = cherrypy.url())
index.exposed = True    

_application = cherrypy.Application(Root(), None)

import posixpath

def application(environ, start_response):
    environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = posixpath.dirname(environ['SCRIPT_NAME'])
    if environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/':
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''
        return _application(environ, start_response)
```